# Terminate Firefox Gracefully without Error when Reopens

Tags: windows, firefox, browser, taskkill

I am using `taskkill /f /im firefox.exe` to forcibly restart Firefox that has multiple tabs open.
It terminates the application, but when it reopens, it shows crash error.

Is there any way to terminate Firefox cleanly/gracefully so it does not prompts that message next time it opens?

Comment: Assuming this is a programming question, try searching on "UI automation", or failing that, you could try sending an ALT-F4 via SendInput().

Comment: I've had experience with a similar scenario on Linux. Harry's suggestion of sending keystroke input is the only way I have found to terminate Firefox gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Using `/t` instead of `/f` solved the problem.